# What is a good way to convert %H:%M:%S strings to timespan?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, timespan

I have a data set with most of the data points in `H:M:S` format, such as `20:59:59`, showing the time span used by individual athletes at different laps.

With D3.js, what is the best way to convert it to time spans, i.e. number of seconds?

I tried `parser = d3.timeParse("%H:%M:%S");` but it seems to be very wrong..

Comment: try this~  `dateformat = d3.time.format("%H:%M:%S").parse;`

Comment: If you are not bound to D3 alone, you might want to have a look at moment.js which comes with built-in support for [durations](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using D3 3.x, then you can construct a suitable parser with:

```
var parser=d3.time.format("%H:%M:%S");
```

or if you were using D3 4.x:

```
var parser=d3.timeParse("%H:%M:%S");
```

Either way, you would then be able to convert your data points into JS Date objects like this:

```
var t1 = parser.parse("20:59:59");
var t2 = parser.parse("21:02:13");
```

You can find out the elapsed time between these two time instances by subtracting, eg:

```
var elapsed = t2 - t1; /* Returns 134000 = 134 seconds */
```

`elapsed` will be the number of elapsed milliseconds.

The reason that works is that Date objects provide a `valueOf()` method which returns the number of milliseconds elapsed since Jan 1 1970. Subtracting the date objects automatically calls `valueOf()` and subtracts the returned values.

Note that if the time strings you are parsing do not include a date portion, then you will have problems if the starting time and ending time are not in the same day.

**EDIT**:

From the comments it becomes clear that the times you are working with are already lap durations, in H:M:S format, and you want to convert them to seconds. That does not require D3, it is easy enough:

```
var components = /^(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)$/.exec("20:59:59");
var elapsedSecs = components[1]*3600+components[2]*60+components[3];
```

Comment: Thanks very much. So I am correct that, for my case, for each lap time, I need to construct a second time that's "00:00:00" and then calculate the elapsed time as you suggested?

Comment: Are you trying to calculate the number of seconds between two times, or the number of seconds since midnight? I would have thought you would have the time instant of each lap, so the elapsed time per lap would be the difference between the time of one lap and the previous one

Comment: Each datapoint is a string in H:M:S format showing the duration of that lap, not the actual time.

Comment: That wasn't entirely clear from the question. In that case a far simpler solution is just to parse it yourself with a regex and calculate H*3600+M*60+S

Comment: Thanks @harmic. Maybe that's faster, just to split the 3 numbers and calculate the seconds. Thought there's something in D3.js for the convenience..

Answer (score 0):

You can use `d3.time.format("%H:%M:%S")` for your conversion.